# Excel function, exclude dates in chart data source

Tags: excel

I am forming a chart from sheet A. Sheet B contains all my data.
I want to exclude a specified date(s).

Sample data:

```
+---+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |    A     |      B       |      C       |      D      |      E      |      F      |
+---+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | Date     | 29/03/2017   | 30/03/2017   | 31/03/2017  | 03/04/2017  | 04/04/2017  |
| 2 | Number 1 | -594590.4649 | -636666.4504 | 795637.1614 | 842563.4322 | 496463.9301 |
| 3 | Number 2 | 2189587.44   | 1301681.418  | 2080839.353 | 1945335.214 | 2421728.123 |
+---+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The final output would be me excluding 30/03/2017 , and keeping the rest in my data selected for my chart.
the issue is that I want to maybe exclude a date in the middle of my selected range. But since this may be a hassle to input a long formula each time into my data selected. I would like to see if there is any formula/function to eliminate a specified date/column. Perhaps manually enter the column you want to exclude in a formula.

My current range is something like `=Graph!$AB$5:$KA$7`  But is there a function to exclude one of these columns?

I can manually select which dates with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but seems tedious.

Comment: excelguy, thanks for your interesting problem. Is there any problem with duplicating the data to a new sheet, and manually remove the columns that need excluding? That would be the simplest solution.